# Grails DetachedCriteria loads too many records

Tags: grails, grails-orm

**Situation**:
In our data model one `AbstractResource`  has many `Availability`. We want to find Availabilities which match a few conditions and belong to a set of AbstractResources. `InternalResource`and `ExternalResource` both extend `AbstractResource`.

We search for the set of resources for which we are interested in Availabilities. This is done with the first two `DetachedCriteria`.
`InternalResource` and `ExternalResource` need to be filtered differently. This implies that we can not merge the first two criterias into the last one using a JOIN.

**Problem**:
When we execute this we expect to get only availabilities with a resource that is in `resources`. Unfortunately this is not *always* the case. From time to time it works. But sometimes it contains availabilities with other resources.

We did a quick test using Hibernates `Criteria`. When we tested this, it worked well.

Are there known restrictions for the usage of `DetachedCriteria` as they are not linked to a specific hibernate session?

```
DetachedCriteria<InternalResource> intResourceCriteria = new DetachedCriteria<>(InternalResource)
intIesourceCriteria.build {
    ...
}
def resources = intResourceCriteria.list()

DetachedCriteria<ExternalResource> extResourceCriteria = new DetachedCriteria<>(ExternalResource)
resourceCriteria.build {
    ...
}
resources.addAll(extResourceCriteria.list())

DetachedCriteria<Availability> availabilityCriteria = new DetachedCriteria<>(Availability)
availabilityCriteria.build {
    'in'('resource', resources)
    ...
}
def availabilities = availabilityCriteria.list()
```

We use the following versions:

- Hibernate 4.3.6.1
- Grails 2.4.4

Comment: `From time to time it works. But sometimes it contains availabilities with other resources.`  then something in this `resourceCriteria.build {
    ...`  not shown - you need to put in debug and work out what query is being generated - this is too broad

Comment: I agree with @vahid. Basically, you're not accounting for an edge-case in your data. I recommend working it out in plain SQL first. Once you have a working SQL query, you can look into implementing it with a criteria query. In the case it's not possible with a criteria query, you can use HQL, or just fall back to SQL.